# How to trace a loop causing heavy memory usage in Python?

Tags: python, loops, memory-management

How can I trace heavy memory usage from a python application that is eating up processing power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic approach is that Python has a built in trace feature which prints every line as it runs `python -mtrace --trace script.py`, which will effectively shows you which lines are creating the unwanted memory usage. To fix the loop that is causing this a `time.sleep(0.1)` does the trick.